# What is a batch in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensor

The introductory documentation, which I am reading ([TOC here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/)) uses the term "batch" ([for instance here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification)) without having defined it.

Comment: hello, batch (epoch, iteration, ..) is actually not computing-related. you can refer to this CV's question to get the general idea and implications of batch size on the performance of your model: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network

Answer (score 98):

Let's say you want to do digit recognition (MNIST) and you have defined your architecture of the network (CNNs). Now, you can start feeding the images from the training data one by one to the network, get the prediction (till this step it's called as doing *inference*), compute the loss, compute the gradient, and then update the parameters of your network (i.e. *weights* and *biases*) and then proceed with the next image ... This way of training the model is sometimes called as *online learning*.

But, you want the training to be faster, the gradients to be less noisy, and also take advantage of the power of GPUs which are efficient at doing array operations (*nD-arrays* to be specific). So, what you instead do is feed in **say 100 images at a time** (the choice of this size is up to you (i.e. it's a *hyperparameter*) and depends on your problem too). For instance, take a look at the below picture, (Author: Martin Gorner)

[image: Batch size of 100]

Here, since you're feeding in 100 images(`28x28`) at a time (instead of 1 as in the online training case), the **batch size is 100**. Oftentimes this is called as *mini-batch size* or simply `mini-batch`.

---

Also the below picture: (Author: Martin Gorner)

[image: batch size again]

Now, the matrix multiplication will all just work out perfectly fine and you will also be taking advantage of the highly optimized array operations and hence achieve faster *training* time.

If you observe the above picture, it doesn't matter that much whether you give 100 or 256 or 2048 or 10000 (*batch size*) images as long as it fits in the memory of your (GPU) hardware. You'll simply get that many predictions.

But, please keep in mind that this *batch size* influences the training time, the error that you achieve, the gradient shifts etc., There is no general rule of thumb as to which batch size works out best. Just try a few sizes and pick the one which works best for you. But try not to use large batch sizes since it will overfit the data. People commonly use mini-batch sizes of `32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048`.

---

**Bonus**: To get a good grasp of how crazy you can go with this batch size, please give this paper a read: [weird trick for parallelizing CNNs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5997.pdf)

Comment: So if my training set is 1000 images and I use a batch size of 10, the model parameters will change 10 times every time the full training set is processed?

Comment: Yes, but 100 times actually! (10 * 100 = 1000 train images)

Comment: @kmario23
if you set the batch size to 1 is that essentially stochastic gradient descent? If you set it to the size of the dataset, is that batch gradient descent? And everything in-between (100 in your example above) min-batch gradient descent?

Comment: @kmario23 what's the tradeoff between a small and large batch size? Too small and you might be underutilizing the memory on the GPU? and too large you might...?

Comment: I believe the trade-off is between computational speed and how well/fast the gradient descent actually converges. This post covers it well: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/tradeoff-batch-size-vs-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neural-network

Comment: @eggie5 having a bigger batch size results to a lower variance of the model, since what the model learns is the "general" trend in your entire dataset. This is good for convex optimization problems. However, if you have a highly non convex optimization problem, meaning there are a lot of local minima in your loss function, it's better to choose a smaller batch size. This will effectively make your model jump out of a local minima. It also results to a faster training time. So a small enough batch size ensures you don't get stuck in a local minima, but big enough to remain in a global minima.

Comment: @Chaine I think the real constraint is that for most large dataset it's not possible to run batch GD. Therefore, there is motivation to try SGD, however, that ignores the computational capacity of modern hardware by not leveraging data parallelism. So, we are led to a mini-batch conclusion.

Comment: Just an aside, I think it's a good idea to shuffle your training data if you are training by batches, especially if the batch size is small.

Comment: Does batch size increase memory usage linearly? If a batch of 2 takes up x amount of RAM then can I expect a batch size of 4 to take up about 2x of RAM?