# Apply tensorflow operations to list of tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to learn word embeddings using cosine similarity between differing translations. `x1` is the embeddings for words in an English sentence. `x2` is the embeddings for words in the correct Inuktitut translation. `x3` is the embeddings for words in the wrong Inuktitut translation. I'm trying to maximize the cosine similarity between `x1` and `x2` and minimize it between `x1` and `x3`. There are many triplets of sentences for which I have to do this. My current training function is the following:

```
def train(self):
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            total_loss = 0
            for x1, x2, x3 in zip(self.x1_list, self.x2_list, self.x3_list):
                norm1 = tf.norm(x1, axis=1)
                norm2 = tf.norm(x2, axis=1)
                norm3 = tf.norm(x3, axis=1)
                cos1 = tf.matmul(x1, x2, transpose_b=True) / norm2
                cos1 = tf.transpose(tf.transpose(cos1) / norm1)
                cos2 = tf.matmul(x1, x3, transpose_b=True) / norm3
                cos2 = tf.transpose(tf.transpose(cos2) / norm1)
                loss = tf.reduce_mean(cos2) - tf.reduce_mean(cos1)
                optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.eta).minimize(loss)
                self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
                _, loss = self.session.run([optimizer, loss])
                total_loss += loss
            if epoch % 5 == 0 or epoch == self.epochs-1:
                print("Epoch {}: loss = {}".format(epoch, total_loss))
```

I don't want to recreate all of the tensorflow operations in each loop iteration, but since `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` are Variables, I can't use placeholders for them. Is there a way to apply these operations to a list of Variable tensors?

Comment: why cant you combine the list x1, x2, x3 as a `batch` and pass it to the network?

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: then you dont need to loop over every features in the list. Form a batch, generate a loss and then sum the losses over the batch and then minimize

Comment: Do you mean `tf.train.batch`? I'll need to look into how to use it.

Comment: I mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175401/what-is-a-batch-in-tensorflow