# What is the meaning of `MiniBatchSize` parameter in LSTM Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I am using the LSTM structure:

```
layers = [ ...
    sequenceInputLayer(1)
    bilstmLayer(100,'OutputMode','last')
    fullyConnectedLayer(2)
    softmaxLayer
    classificationLayer
    ];

options = trainingOptions('adam', ...
    'MaxEpochs',30, ...
    'MiniBatchSize', 150, ...
    'InitialLearnRate', 0.01, ...
    'GradientThreshold', 1, ...
    'plots','training-progress', ...
    'Verbose',false);
```

and `net = trainNetwork(XTrain,Ytrain,layers,options);`

where

- `Xtrain` is 1x100 cell array (`Xtrain{1,1}` gives a data array of size 1000x1, `Xtrain{1,2}` is another set of data array of size 1000x1 etc). This means that I have 100 examples of feature vectors each example is of dimension 1000.
- `Ytrain` is the response variable 0/1 and is an array of size 100x1. The response is of type double.

I simply assumed the `MiniBatchSize` parameter as 150. I tried with other values as well say 50,60,70...nothing seems to influence the performance. So I don't exactly follow what this parameter denotes and how to find a value for it. Can somebody please help in explaining what this means and ideally what it should be? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is actually explained on the [Mathworks documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/trainingoptions.html#bu59f0q-MiniBatchSize):

> Size of the mini-batch to use for each training iteration, specified
>   as the comma-separated pair consisting of `MiniBatchSize` and a
>   positive integer. A mini-batch is a subset of the training set that is
>   used to evaluate the gradient of the loss function and update the
>   weights. See Stochastic Gradient Descent.

As for what it is, there exist several answers on the web, both on Stackexchange websites  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175401/what-is-a-batch-in-tensorflow) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network) and [elsewhere on the web](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-mini-batch-gradient-descent-configure-batch-size/). Generally, it should influence the convergence of your optimization algorithm, and how much memory is used during the computation.
Note that it is generally preferred by now [to use smaller batch sizes](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/989610208497360896?lang=de), as long as you don't have too much training data.